# Using LINQ and Entity how do I return values of a many-to-many relationship

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I have two entities, Account and Subscription with a many-to-many association between them. I can't seem to find in the tutorials anywhere how to do the following:

I want to find all the Accounts with a Subscription of type x. If I wasn't using the Entity framework I could join to the AccountSubscription table, but that isn't accessible via Entity. Do I have to create a special entity if I need to query on a many-to-many relationship?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF should create a navigation property for a many-to-many relationship.  Then you should be able to do something like this:

```
var accounts = from a in Accounts
               where a.Subscriptions.Any(s => s.SubscriptionType == "something")
               select a;
```

For example, I have a simple db with a many to many relationship between Products and Groups:
[image]

And EF creates the association in the model:
[image]

So I can create a query like this (here including the Groups so I can see the Category):

[image]

Comment: what are you using to display the results?

Comment: @SnOrfus, using [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/), which also allows you to view the SQL generated by EF.  *Highly* recommended :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
List<Accounts> myAccounts = //get accounts;

foreach(Accounts a in myAccounts)
{
  foreach(Subscriptions s in a)
  {
     //add it to a global list?
  } 
}
```

Comment: This will simply pull everything off from database and cause major problem in performance!