# Interrogating a many to many table in the entity framework

Tags: linq, entity-framework-4

Say I have two tables in the Entity Framework, Library and Book. These are on a many to many join with another table inbetween called Library_Book but it is hidden as it is the join table.

How would I check using LINQ whether a library had a certain book by interrogating the join table (which doesnt have its own class in the Entity Framework) without returning the list of all the books in a library from the join table but instead only the record which has the bookId and the LibraryId.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Using LINQ and Entity how do I return values of a many-to-many relationship](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235978/using-linq-and-entity-how-do-i-return-values-of-a-many-to-many-relationship/4235997#4235997)

Answer (score 1):

To determine if known library has a known book, you could do something like this:

```
bool hasIt = (from l in Libraries from b in l.Books where b.Id == 5 where l.Id == 3 
select l).Any();
```

This Linq query will not touch either the Library or Books table.  It will look like this:

```
    SELECT 
CASE WHEN ( EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[LibraryBookIntersection] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE (5 = [Extent1].[BookId]) AND (3 = [Extent1].[LibraryId])
)) THEN cast(1 as bit) WHEN ( NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[LibraryBookIntersection] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE (5 = [Extent2].[BookId]) AND (3 = [Extent2].[LibraryId])
)) THEN cast(0 as bit) END AS [C1]
FROM  ( SELECT 1 AS X ) AS [SingleRowTable1]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have set up some values in the join table Library_Book and tested the above LINQ statement but it sometimes returns true when I am expecting false and vice versa. It appears sparadic. Any ideas on why this maybe?

Comment: @user375564 you would have to post your Linq query, and then show me the TSQL you're using to validate that the true or false is not correct.

Comment: bool hasIt = (from l in _ctx.Liraries
                          from b in _ctx.Books
                          where l.Id == 1
                          where b.Id == 3
                          select l).Any();

select COUNT(*) from Libray_Book where idLibrary = 1 and idBook = 3

the first returns hasIt = True but the second statement returns 0 as it should do

Comment: but in your clase you're not joining libraries to contact logs. Essentially your saying if there are any libraries with and ID == 1 OR any contactLogs where the ID == 3.  If there is a many to many between libraries and contactlogs then you'll need to use that navigation property to get the join.  In my example my second from clause is from the books of the l iterator variable.

Comment: silly me. You are quite right. There was no join. Thanks from your help. I will now attempt to write this using lambdas. Cheers

Comment: There is a check mark below the up and down arrows for voting on an answer. Press the check mark (and if it's the accepted answer, it wouldn't hurt to vote on it as well)  http://yfrog.com/0xnb3p